# Load/Run external code at runtime

Tags: c++

I am attempting to update components of my c++ QT application as opposed to updating the whole application.

What are my options to load in code/new components at runtime? My application is for Linux and Windows. Is my only option a Dynamically Loaded Library file? Are there other options in C++ to do this?

Comment: Yes dynamic linking is the way to go, it's exactly just what you are looking for.

Comment: What other way would there be? Loading code is done by the OS. Either stick to what the OS provides or write some really dark hack.

Comment: @Paul It doesn't *have to be* done by the OS - see e.g. Wine. It's just much more convenient to ask the OS to do it than to try to do it yourself.

Comment: Creating separate executables, launching them and communicating via pipes?

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, thats a method I didn't think of. I could also use dbus to communicate aswell

Comment: Check out [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)